# Java custom annotation for a behaviour like trim

Tags: java, annotations, trim

I have to write the trim functionality like below.

```
public void setUserComment (String value) {
    this.userComment  = (value != null) ? value.trim() : value;
}
```

But this needs to apply this in lots of places in our existing place.
any idea that uses custom annotation for this behavior. like.

```
@MyCustomTrim
public void setUserComment (String value) {
    this.userComment  = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes we can easily done by

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeSerializer.class)
private String name;
```

Now Implement your the customDeSerializer as below

```
public class CustomDeSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
@Override
public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx)
        throws IOException {
    String str = p.getText();
    try {
        return str.trim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try below code at controller level:

```
@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {

dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        if (text == null) {
            return;
        }
        setValue(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        Object value = getValue();
        return (value != null ? value.trim().toString() : "");
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing java annotations results (in its standard way) to the creation of new classes.
I don't think that you are looking for that.

As alternative, you could use AOP (AspectJ or Spring).
You could for example :

- define an aspect that performs the repeated processing (trim the `String` if not null)
- create your own annotation (as your in question)
- add the annotation on the methods where you want to apply the aspect
- specify the pointcut on the method execution that have this annotation.

As I don't know whether you use Spring or not and if your objects where you want to apply the repeated processing are Spring beans or not, I prefer not to give a specific solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: We are not using Spring.
We are using EJB3, with JPA in Java 8.


What is your first point.. //Processing java annotations results (in its standard way) to the creation of new classes.//

Comment: You could use AspectJ in this case. My first point refers to `javax/annotation.processing.Processor` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html.